# Django - How to call delete_selected() method?

Tags: django, django-admin

```
from django.contrib.admin.actions import delete_selected
from Test.app.models import Post
from django.contrib import admin

class PostModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields= ('gender',)
    list_display = ('gender',) 

    def mark_deleted(self, request, queryset):
         print "deleted"
         return delete_selected(self, request, queryset)

actions = [mark_deleted,]

admin.site.register(Post, PostModelAdmin)
```

I just called the default bulk delete functions. It produces the following error.

```
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'PostModelAdmin' object has no attribute 'model'
```

What  I need to pass for 'modeladmin' attribute?

def delete_selected(modeladmin, request, queryset):

## New issue

All the error are gone now. But none of the objects got deleted. This action always says like 'No Objects selected'. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The action is expecting a ModelAdmin instance, not a class. `self` is the right thing to pass here.

Comment: Thanks. But it is not showing the delete confirmation page and objects are also not getting deleted.

Comment: Just added the 'return', But it always says no objects selected.

Comment: @Siva did youever got this solved? I stumbled about the exactly same problem today

Comment: I found a solution for this in the following blog entry: [link](http://k4ml.github.io/django-admin-hook-into-actions.html)